# Как сделать на JavaScript дополнительный слой на имеющейся разметке

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть готовый сайт уже с разметкой. На этом сайте есть некоторые `div`-ы.

Я пишу модуль который случайным образом сгенерирует разные SVG фигуры и поместит их над фоном заданных `div`-ов, при этом текст и содержание div-а останутся поверх фона и svg.

Пример:
Исходные данные - **слой1**: зелёный фон, **слой2**: текст

Мне надо сделать JavaScript функцию которая сделает следующее.

**слой1**: зелёный фон, **слой1.5**: мои фигуры SVG, которые я умею генерировать, **слой2**: текст.

То есть мне надо заинжектить между фоном и содержанием блока мой SVG.

Какие есть варианты как это можно сделать, что бы разметка сайта которая уже есть не поехала.

Что я хочу сделать: я просто добавляю на сайт на window.onload функцию которая инжектит в некоторые div-ы мой SVG, при этом не меняя разметку сайта, точнее если без этого не обойтись то и разметку могу поменять, но хочется либо обойтись вообще без этого либо с минимальными изменениями.

Comment: я ноль в js но от тебя не ожидал такого вопроса ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский почему не ожидали? Если вы имеете ввиду что слишком простая задача для меня... вообщем я могу её решить, просто подумал что интересная задача будет интересна многим людям. Тем более думаю что решений может быть много, а мне хочется найти решение покрасивее.

Comment: я  смотрел видео на youtube, там один чувак из фоток делал lazy эффект с фоками + к тому же они были волнистые -- т.е появление было волнами .. очень эффектно смотрится - так там кода было на три страницы .. применлось там твинмакс + canvas + куча опыта и этот чувак утверждал что он не знает js...извени за отступление ... могу скинуть это видео если хочешь